# Need to eliminate these "else if" and optimize the code

Tags: c++

This should be easy for you but it is been a pain in the ass for me. I want to count from 16 to 0 and show and image at each step.

The problem is that it is too big for Arduino, I know that I can improve the else if conditions, I tried with arrays, but can't figure how to :(

Maybe you can help me the actual code is the following one  (I deleted the definition of some of the images because of the lenght of the post)

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define OLED_RESET 4
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_RESET);

static const unsigned char PROGMEM logo16[] = {
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x03, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0,
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x00, 0x0F, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x80, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x3F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xC0, 0x0F, 0xFF, 0x01, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x80, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x1F, 0xFF, 0x03, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x80, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF0, 0x1F, 0xFF, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x80, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF0, 0x3F, 0xFF, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x80, 0x20,
0x01, 0x01, 0xFE, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0xF8, 0x3F, 0x1F, 0x07, 0xE0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x7F, 0x1F, 0x07, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x7E, 0x1F, 0x07, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xF8, 0xFC, 0x1F, 0x07, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x07, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x80, 0x20,
0x01, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xC0, 0x20,
0x01, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x20,
0x01, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x20,
0x01, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x20,
0x01, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x07, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0xE0, 0x20,
0x01, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x07, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0xE0, 0x20,
0x01, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x07, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0xE0, 0x20,
0x01, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x07, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0xE0, 0x20,
0x01, 0x01, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF0, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF0, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xC0, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x03, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xC0, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x1F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x01, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x80, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x00, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x03, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0,
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};



static const unsigned char PROGMEM logo00[] = {
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0xFF, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xFC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF0, 0x0C, 0x03, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xC0, 0x70, 0x1F, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x01, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x01, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x0C, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x70, 0x3F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x01, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x01, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x0C, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x70, 0x3F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x01, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x01, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x0C, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x70, 0x3F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x01, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x01, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x0C, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x70, 0x3F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x01, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x01, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x0C, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x70, 0x3F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x01, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x01, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x0C, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x70, 0x3F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x01, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x01, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x0C, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x70, 0x3F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x01, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x01, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x0C, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x70, 0x3F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x01, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x01, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x0C, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x70, 0x3F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x01, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x01, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x0C, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x70, 0x3F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x01, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x0C, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xC0, 0x70, 0x1F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x01, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xFC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x70, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xFE, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F,
0xFC, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F
};

#define SSD1306_LCDHEIGHT 64

#if (SSD1306_LCDHEIGHT != 64)
#error("Height incorrect, please fix Adafruit_SSD1306.h!");
#endif


const int buttonPin = 2;
int buttonPushCounter = 0;   
int buttonState = 0;         
int lastButtonState = 0;     


void setup()   {                
  Serial.begin(9600);
 display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);
  display.display();
  delay(2000);


  display.clearDisplay();


 pinMode(buttonPin,INPUT); 

   display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo16, 128,64,WHITE);
      display.display();
}


void loop() {

 buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
    if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {

    if (buttonState == HIGH) {

      buttonPushCounter++;
      if (buttonPushCounter==1) {
        display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo16, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
      }
      else if (buttonPushCounter==2) {
        display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo15, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
      }
else if (buttonPushCounter==3) {
        display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo14, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
      }

else if (buttonPushCounter==4) {
        display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo13, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
      }
      else if (buttonPushCounter==5) {
        display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo12, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
      }
      else if (buttonPushCounter==6) {
        display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo11, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
      }
      else if (buttonPushCounter==7) {
        display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo10, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
      }
      else if (buttonPushCounter==8) {
        display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo09, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
      }
      else if (buttonPushCounter==9) {
        display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo08, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
      }
      else if (buttonPushCounter==10) {
        display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo07, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
      }
        else if (buttonPushCounter==11) {
        display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo06, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
      }
        else if (buttonPushCounter==12) {
        display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo05, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
      }
        else if (buttonPushCounter==13) {
        display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo04, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
      }
        else if (buttonPushCounter==14) {
        display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo03, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
      }
        else if (buttonPushCounter==15) {
        display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo02, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
      }
        else if (buttonPushCounter==16) {
        display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo01, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
      }
        else if (buttonPushCounter==17) {
        display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo00, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
         display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo00, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
         display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo00, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
         display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo00, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
      }
    } 
    else {

    delay(50);
  }

  lastButtonState = buttonState;


  }

}
```

Comment: Have a map of lambdas?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean :S

Comment: `display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logoXX, 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);` is repeated many times and crying out for a function with `logoXX` as a parameter.

Comment: That is what I don't know how to do. I tried with a "for" but keep throwing errors

Comment: *"The problem is that it is too big for Arduino"* Is it not the 16 arrays instead of your code ?

Comment: Wow. Speak of the wrong way to do things.

Comment: @NathanOliver Since the possible values of `buttonPushCounter` are sequential, you could even use a vector.

Comment: With an array of images, you might do `display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo[17 - buttonPushCounter], 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);`

Comment: This is probably why 8 bit games used pallets and no brightness resolution to store their images.

Comment: @patatahooligan, back in them days, the video display _hardware_ typically expected 8-bits per pixel and a color palette.

Comment: @jameslarge Trying to find where I remember that from, it seems to be from [this](https://youtu.be/Tfh0ytz8S0k) video and it turns out it was about the Commodore 64. And yes it was how the hardware worked, but you can software engineer the same idea to compress an image.

Comment: I wrote an array for the images, and did what @Jarod42 told me. Now I have a "call of overload"problem at the drawbitmap :(
And I don't know how can I manage this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define an array of arrays for your logos. Then you could access the separate logos by index. The following (simplified) code shows how to define and access such an array:

```
static const unsigned char logos[16][128] = {
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }, // complete with all values...
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 },
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }
    // .. complete the remaining 13 lines...
};

void print(const unsigned char logo[128]) {
    // some code here...
}

int main() {
    for(int i=15;i>=0;i--) {
        print(logos[i]);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am really a noob at this, so It tried something similar

I added an array 
`int logo[] = {logo1, logo2, logo3};`
and then
`void loop() {

   buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

if (buttonState == HIGH) {
   
  for (count=1;count<3;count++) {
   display.clearDisplay();
        display.drawBitmap(0,-15, logo[count], 128,64,WHITE);
        display.display();
        delay(200);
  }

}
 lastButtonState = buttonState;
 }
`

But it show "call of overloaded drawbitmap" :(
BTW I don't know how to post like a normalperson